# How can I change the class name of CEdit object embeded in a MFC dialog

Tags: windows, mfc

I have a MFC dialog that contains a CEdit object inside. By default, if using Spy++ to query the class name of CEdit, it is "Edit". I wanna change its name to my private class name.
Does anyon have any idea?

Comment: Do you have the code to this app? Do you have a window class at hand with your private class name?

Answer (score 0):

Create own own CEdit class derived from CEdit (e.g. class CEditEx : public CEdit ) and override the Create function of CEdit in your CEditEx class. At this point you can give a name to the Window you are creating.

Answer (score 0):

What possible good reason do you have to want to do this?

If you are creating a window from scratch, it makes sense.  But if all you want to do is change the name you see in Spy++, I think it is rather pointless. Spend your time doing something productive.

You have to *successfully* register a WNDCLASS object ahead of time before you call the DoModal() or Create() function of the dialog. In the dialog resource, you will have to change your "EDIT" control to a custom class and put the name of that custom class name in the resource template.

But, again, what problem are you hoping to solve that you can't solve by subclassing an EDIT control? You might want to search Raymond Chen's blog for reasons you might or might not want to do what you're asking of us.